# Backup partitions belong to root, how do I fix it?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, permissions, backup, root

I've did a clean install of Ubuntu on my Notebook. I created 3 partitions, swap, the ubuntu partition, and a backup or files partition (located in /media/Backup).

The thing that I don't understand is why my backup partitions permission are set for ROOT only. I've changed using `sudo` plus `chown`, but in previous versions of Ubuntu, I never had this kind of inconvenience.

Does anybody know why this is set for root after installing?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I suppose every partition is "root owned," because only root can access the block device.  I am assuming you mean, though, that the files are owned by root.

To change ownership from root to your user on a partition mounted on **/media/Backup**, run this:

`sudo chown matt -R /media/Backup/`  ,  where **matt** is your user.

If after this, you cannot access your files as a regular user, post the output of:

`ls -l /media/Backup/`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the portion of the the question "why my backup partitions permission are set for ROOT only?"
 
The most likely answer is that you used sudo when making the backup. By doing so you would have executed the command as root, and the files created would then belong to root.

How did you create the Backups by the way? Did you use tar, rsync, cp, or another application?